# Can GCP service accounts list GCE VMs created for GAE Flex services?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, app-engine-flexible

Our project uses App Engine Flexible Environment and we would like to automate discovery of the GCE VMs underlying our App Engine flex services.

In theory, this should be possible using the [v1/compute/instances.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1/compute.instances.list) API. And, this API works using my own credentials: all GCE VMs are returned, including App Engine Flex VMs.

However, when I switch to using service account credentials, the call to instances.list succeeds, but all App Engine Flex VMs are excluded from the returned list!

This not an issue of scopes or service account privilege. The same scopes are used whether I authenticate using my own credentials or a service account. And, I have tried assigning the service account up to the "Owner" Role, but see the same behavior from instances.list.

Can Google service accounts list all GCE VMs? If so, how? If not why? Is there a special filter that excludes app engine flexible environment VMs *only* when service accounts are used to list them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we use GCE virtual machines under the hood, they're not entirely exposed in the same way. If you're looking for access to instance information for App Engine (flex or standard), you should be looking at this API:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list

You can also get this by running:

`gcloud app instances list`

That will probably get you where you're trying to go.  Let us know if you have any questions!

Comment: Okay, thank you. I've confirmed the app engine API lists these instances using a service account for authentication.